# Need to sync many PCs to a single one, looking for easy ideas

Tags: ssh, rsync, cron

I am trying to wrap my head around using Rsync. I basically want to setup a "server" that will act as a repository for files that I want to keep synced with MANY other machines. I am just starting down this road and I am confused about using rsync over ssh using rsa keys. I have found many tutorials on how to make this happen, but my question is this. Do I need a separate rsa key for each "client" and have that on the "server" Or can I use one key for all clients? I may have hundreds of clients (hope, hope). I have figured out how to make it work manually now for the automatic part. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: You might consider storing the data on a sever and have them map a drive, etc. to it instead. This way the client's data that they update is what it is right where it is. You'd not need to sync data via this method perhaps and seems it would be more efficient than having a client write files, etc. and then sync those up with another server or locations. Just have them access it across the network somehow and go that method... Maybe, maybe now, but that's a quick idea... Jimmy John'... Grab a Bucket

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a file share on the server; Windows share for Windows clients, and NFS share for Linux clients.

If you must use rsync, you could push from the server to the clients.  To grant permission for the server on a client, run this from the server:

```
ssh-copy-id username@client1
```

Then you would push out a directory sync like this, assuming same username on each:

```
for client in client1 client2 client3 client4 client5; do
    rsync -avz /full/path/ username@$client:/full/path/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about hundreds of clients then IMHO it better to use some sort of synchronization software. It could be a [git](https://git-scm.com/), [fossil-scm](http://fossil-scm.org/) or [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) in master mode. With the latest one you don't need to mess up with clients SSL certificates at all and it works practically on any platform. `git` and `fossil` can be served over HTTPS so no need to manage a lot of certificates. By using such approach you will eliminate extra job to manage access to your server.  `rsync` is really good, but IMHO not in your scenario since you would need to manage secure SSH server and mess up with bunch of certificates.